# Editing and inserting a line after reading it with Bash

Tags: bash

I am using a while read loop to process a file. (I have redirected the standard input of the **while read do done** block to my file)

I want to edit this line when some conditions on its fields are matched, or insert a new line before it.
However I do not know how to do it. It seems that awk could do what I want, but can I do it in bash ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.  See [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/) URL.. it is well written.  I myself would probably use `sed` and not try to process the file.. but that is up to you and depends on what you are actually trying to do.  As far as the concept.. you will read in lines from one file and write them to another.  Whan complete, delete file 1 and rename file 2 to file 1s name.

Comment: I think this page does not explain how to modify the file from which we read... Would redirecting both stdin and stdout to myfile work ? (I mean "done <myfile > myfile" after the while read loop). Will the "cursors" be synchronized ?

Comment: IMO Bash is not a good tool to modify files in place. `foo <file >file` [never works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110492/108618). Write to another file and then either atomically move the new file over the old one or truncate the old one and write the content of the new one to the old one (these two methods are not equivalent). Also see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37177/108618).

Comment: As @Kamil_Maciorowski points out.. and you will see in my first comment, you don't modify the file, you write a new file using `echo $stuff >yer_file_name.tmp` for each line you process and want in the new file.  Then you delete to old file and rename your temp file to the deleted file's name.. actually Kamil said this better than I just did :-P

Comment: You are right, I was making things unnecessary complicated, it's better to just write to a file. I originally wanted to edit it in-place because I only change about 10% of the lines.